# Sitecore EE Ctrl+Click equivalent for Mac

Tags: experience-editor

In the Sitecore EE on a Windows machine you can hold the ctrl key and then click on a link to force Sitecore to navigate to the link.

What is the equivalent on Mac? We have tried "CMD+click", "ctrl+click", "alt+click".

Comment: I think it is ctrl + option + click. Similar to how you select multiple files in explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this.

ctrl + option + click

Comment: The user I am testing with just gets the context menu.

Comment: What browser are you on?